# Angular 9.0 ngserve throwing "Invalid Token" errors in vendor.js file

Tags: angular, angular9

I just updated to Angular 9, and when I try to run ngserve I'm getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" errors in the vendor.js file. I've now gotten this error multiple times, usually on different lines of the vendor.js file (first on Line 35xxx, then on Line 15xxx, and now on Line 7xxx). Inspecting that file in the browser always shows some "�" characters where I would expect legible characters, so it seems the ngserve process might be running into problems while generating that file, and inserting incorrect/garbage characters? This latest example is on Line 7618 of vendor.js, and the Chrome network inspector shows that line as:

```
return new _angular_animations__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["NoopAnimationPlayer"](timelineInstruction.duration, �BC�\��Instruction.delay);
```

I have no idea where to begin for fixing this issue. It's completely preventing my website from loading, so I'm basically stuck.

Comment: did you check the encoding of your files , please make sure that you use utf8 (even your machine or IDE ..) must use utf8

Answer (score 0):

is usually an encoding problem,
in your case, you get this problem because of the Unicode of the `vendor.js`
make sure it uses `utf8`

Comment: I've made sure that the index.html file includes both <!doctype html> and <meta charset="utf-8">. Is there another file that I should be checking for that encoding information?I was under the impression that the ngserve-generated vendor.js file was generated on the fly and wasn't something I could open for edit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue may have been caused be the "ag-grid" plugin for Angular not playing nicely with the new "Ivy" rendering in Angular 9+, and the error was in Angular itself in a way that a plugin update would not resolve the issue.

The solution was to update to Angular v10.